# How to pass the value of a variable into a mongo query?

Tags: python, mongodb

The following mongo query works correctly:
`db.data.find({"data.id": "5" })`

I want to pass the value of a variable for an argument list to the query in a python program:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client=MongoClient()
db=client.dhlab
data=db.data

for data in db.data.find({"data.id":'"' $id '"'}):
   print data
```

I tried the following for `db.data.find({"data.id":id})` without success:
`/"id/", '"'id'"',  /"$id/"`

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the value of here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
result = db.data.find({"data.id": {$in: [1,2,3,5]} })

for data in result:
    print(data) // will print all 'data' document whith that id
```

You can replace [1,2,3,5] whith your own values or a variable.
For example:

```
range(1,5) # is equal to [1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3] # it takes ids equal to 1,2 or 3
```

We could consider this situation ( we want to use just even numbers ):

```
list = []
numbers = range(1,100)
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 0
        list.append(number)

result = db.data.find({"data.id": { $in: list } })
```